# Can't reinstall unity control

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I have purged `bluez` using the command

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove bluez
```

but `unity-control-center` also got uninstalled.

I can not reinstall it any more, it shows this error message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install unity-control-center

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: indicator-bluetooth but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My system is Ubuntu 14.04.

How can I fix this issue and get the Unity control center back?

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy unity-control-center bluez indicator-bluetooth` to your question by [edit]ing it and leaving me a comment as notification afterwards. Thanks.